# Real-time classification of audio - thousands of classes

Tags: classification, time-series, audio-recognition

There is a need to classify an audio stream in real-time - using one from thousands of the defined classes. Up to 5000 classes potentially.

What's the best machine learning algorithm for this task?

DTW? HMM? SVM? Some specific DSP algorithms?

Comment: Anything that doesn't require extracting expensive features; something that works with FFTs and MFCCs, such as a modern neural network should be fine. The training complexity is not an issue in your case.

Comment: Could give some example of the classes? Is your problem similar to speech recognition?

Comment: Yes, similar to speech recognition, but discovering such things as "car engine", "scream", "human steps", "dog barks" etc.

Comment: SVM should work too.